# Working with System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent

Tags: powershell

I'm pulling data from SQL using System.Data.SqlClient and eventaully end up with a dataset stored into a variable:

```
$SqlQuery = "select * from my_Table"
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server = $SQLServer; Database = $SQLDBName; Integrated Security = True"
$SqlConnection.Open()

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $SqlQuery
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd

$amManagedFolders = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($dataset)
```

I then access the table via `$dataset.Tables[0]` which is of type: `System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent`

I need to be able to use `ForEach` in order to loop through that table and store the results into a `CustomPSObject` for later use, however, I am not sure of a method to use in order to achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerShell - ForEach using SQL data input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23133591/powershell-foreach-using-sql-data-input)

Comment: I need to work straight from the SQL Table in $dataset and ForEach it straight into a CustomObject. This works, what then doesn't work, is querying the custom object.

Comment: This looks very close to a problem I had.  Trying to query a CustomObject.  I ended up importing data as CSV, then piping it to Where-Object and matching my criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Using [this page](http://www.maxtblog.com/2014/06/powershell-extracting-sql-server-data-into-excel/) I found the following code helpful.  I'm taking a SQL query and producing an Excel workbook with the results.

```
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$SqlConnection.Close()
$DataSetTable = $DataSet.Tables["Table"]
## - Build the Excel column heading:
[Array] $getColumnNames = $DataSetTable.Columns | Select ColumnName
## - Build column header:
[Int] $RowHeader = 1
foreach ($ColH in $getColumnNames)
....
foreach ($rec in $DataSetTable.Rows)
{
foreach ($Coln in $getColumnNames)
{
## - Next line convert cell to be text only:
$xlsSh.Cells.NumberFormat = "@"
## - Populating columns:
$xlsSh.Cells.Item($rowData, $colData) = $rec.$($Coln.ColumnName).ToString()
$ColData++
}
$rowData++; $ColData = 1
}
```

-Edit, saw your comment.  You might be able to adapt [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16778525/formatting-powershell-sql-server-output-into-columns-and-rows) to this question